# JQuery name name attribute not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, attr

I am trying to clone the last row of a table and designate new name and ID attributes using jquery.

JQuery function

```
function addTableRow(table){

    var $tr = $(table).find("tbody tr:last").clone();
    $tr.find("input,select,textarea").attr('name', 'test');
    $tr.find("input,select,textarea").attr('id', 'test');
    $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);

}
```

Table row (within PHP)

```
echo '<tr onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">';
echo '<td>Home: </td>';
echo '<td colspan="6"><input type="text" name="home'.$i.'" id="home'.$i.'" value="'.$row['homePhone'].'" style="width: 90px;"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Button (outside PHP)

```
<button onclick="addTableRow(document.getElementById('tableID'));">Add</button>
```

The above code works perfectly in chrome and firefox. In IE9 however, only the id attribute changes, while the name consistently remains unchanged.

What is causing this behavior and how can I make my code work?

Comment: Even better: a fiddle...

Comment: changing the name and id of an input works for me in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/Nye6H/

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. Here you are trying to assign the same ID to all matched elements (input,select,textarea).

Comment: Interestingly, onclick="alert(this.name);" on the element gives the updated name while  onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);" on the row shows the old name with the updated id. I assume the name straight from the element itself is correct but what is causing this unusual behavior?

Comment: @DIodeus those were just place holders to explain my issue

Comment: The whole point of jQuery is to move away from using `onclick` and using jQuery event handling instead. You shouldn't need any JS code embedded in the HTML.